# You don't have permission to access when to set two name-based web sites on a single IP address in apache

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions, virtualhost

Apache was installed on my debian,i want to bind two domain name with different directroy.

```
cat  /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  hwy.local  www.hwy.local  test.app   www.test.app
```

Two domain name all binded with  127.0.0.1.

cat   /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hwy.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_hwy.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_hwy.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.test.app
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot  /home/debian9/app
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_app.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_app.log combined
    <Directory /home/debian9/app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Create file .

```
 touch  /var/log/apache2/error_hwy.log
 touch  /var/log/apache2/access_hwy.log
 touch  /var/log/apache2/error_app.log
 touch  /var/log/apache2/access_app.log
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/debian9/app
 sudo chmod -R g+rw /home/debian9/app
 sudo systemctl restart  apache2
```

Save the same file `test.html`  in both `/var/www/html` and `/home/debian9/app`.

```
<p>it is a test</p>
```

Why `www.hwy.local/test.html` can open it ,`www.test.app`  run into error.

```
`This site can’t be reached` 

curl -i  www.test.app/test.html
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2018 09:08:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Content-Length: 296
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /test.html
on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.test.app Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Can't set `DocumentRoot` for `www.test.app` as  `/home/debian9/app`  which is different from `/var/www/html` for `www.hyw.local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allow from all
```

is the configuration syntax of Apache 2.2. [With Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) this should be

```
Require all granted
```